# Facing different outputs from below two codes

Tags: sql, case, date-arithmetic

Have to get the number of companies that were acquired within a period of 3 years from foundation

Any suggestions for a better code for the same are most welcome!

My code

```
COUNT( CASE WHEN  (acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean::timestamptz) <= (INTERVAL '3 Year') THEN 1
ELSE NULL END )as acquired_3_yrs
```

Website answer

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned <= companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp + INTERVAL '3 years'THEN 
1 ELSE NULL END) AS acquired_3_yrs
```

These both are giving different outputs, the variation is very small.
Kindly explain the difference where did I go wrong.

Comment: Possibly to do with timezone?

Comment: It shows the same result with timestamp or timestamptz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are comparing between different units of time.  If you simply select `acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean`, you will get an answer expressed as so many days and hours.  This cannot be accurately compared with an interval expressed in years.

As a test try simply

```
SELECT (INTERVAL '1080 DAY') <= (INTERVAL '3 YEAR');
```

and

```
SELECT (INTERVAL '1081 DAY') <= (INTERVAL '3 YEAR');
```

The first is true, but the second is false.  Why?  Because there are 12 months in a year.  And how many days in a month?  Effectively Postgres uses a year of 12 months of 30 days.  This is not a bug.  There is no really correct way to do it otherwise (think about leap years!).

The Website answer works correctly because 3 years is added to a specific date, and that will give the expected answer,

Comment: Right! When we guide sql to add an interval on a specific datestamp it makes more sense than comparing a datestamp to any interval(which is vague).